# Permission denied error when installing searx on Ubuntu Server 21.04

Tags: server, software-installation, permissions, vps

I'm trying to install searx on my Ubuntu VPS but when I run `./utils/searx.sh` according to the [official documentation](https://searx.github.io/searx/admin/installation.html#installation-scripts)

I get this error:

```
ls: cannot access '/home/test/searx': Permission denied
ERROR: ./utils/searx.sh: line 385: user 'searx' missed read permission: /home/test/searx
```

What command would I run to fix this? Thank you for any help.

---

```
$ ls -Al /home/test/searx 
total 204
-rw-rw-r--  1 test test  3509 Jul 18 07:12 AUTHORS.rst
-rw-rw-r--  1 test test    97 Jul 18 07:12 babel.cfg
-rw-rw-r--  1 test test 19912 Jul 18 07:12 CHANGELOG.rst
-rw-rw-r--  1 test test   641 Jul 18 07:12 .codecov.yml
-rw-rw-r--  1 test test  1899 Jul 18 07:12 .config.sh
-rw-rw-r--  1 test test  1898 Jul 18 07:12 CONTRIBUTING.md
-rw-rw-r--  1 test test   141 Jul 18 07:12 .coveragerc
-rw-rw-r--  1 test test  4957 Jul 18 07:12 .dir-locals.el
-rw-rw-r--  1 test test  2960 Jul 18 07:12 Dockerfile
drwxrwxr-x  2 test test  4096 Jul 18 07:12 dockerfiles
-rw-rw-r--  1 test test   597 Jul 18 07:12 .dockerignore
drwxrwxr-x 11 test test  4096 Jul 18 07:12 docs
drwxrwxr-x  2 test test  4096 Jul 18 07:12 examples
drwxrwxr-x  8 test test  4096 Jul 18 07:12 .git
-rw-rw-r--  1 test test   494 Jul 18 07:12 .gitattributes
drwxrwxr-x  4 test test  4096 Jul 18 07:12 .github
-rw-rw-r--  1 test test   260 Jul 18 07:12 .gitignore
-rw-rw-r--  1 test test    48 Jul 18 07:12 .landscape.yaml
-rw-rw-r--  1 test test 34520 Jul 18 07:12 LICENSE
-rw-rw-r--  1 test test  2805 Jul 18 07:12 Makefile
-rwxrwxr-x  1 test test 15310 Jul 18 07:12 manage
-rw-rw-r--  1 test test   432 Jul 18 07:12 PULL_REQUEST_TEMPLATE.md
-rw-rw-r--  1 test test 14507 Jul 18 07:12 .pylintrc
-rw-rw-r--  1 test test  2483 Jul 18 07:12 README.rst
-rw-rw-r--  1 test test   384 Jul 18 07:12 requirements-dev.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 test test   325 Jul 18 07:12 requirements.txt
drwxrwxr-x 13 test test  4096 Jul 18 07:12 searx
drwxrwxr-x  3 test test  4096 Jul 18 07:12 searx_extra
-rw-rw-r--  1 test test  2187 Jul 18 07:12 setup.py
drwxrwxr-x  4 test test  4096 Jul 18 07:12 tests
-rw-rw-r--  1 test test    31 Jul 18 07:12 tox.ini
drwxrwxr-x  3 test test  4096 Jul 18 07:12 utils
```

Answer (score 2):

Fixed by cloning searx to `/tmp` folder instead of `/home/user` folder

Answer found here:
https://github.com/searx/searx/discussions/2598

Comment: Can confirm this worked for me with searxng

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the script does not have the right permissions to run in or access the `/home/test/searx` folder. Can you check permissions/owners with

```
ls -Al /home/test/searx
```

You may want to make sure you're running it with `sudo` like the docs specify also.